# Url in function changes when i echo it from php

Tags: javascript, function, url

I have a snackbar (small notification popup) and what i try to do is that when you press on a button the color of the box and the text within changes to set variables. This al works. However if i echo the same function within the onclick of an echoed button it messes up the whole function format (see code below)

If tried changing from " to ' but this does nothing.

The button:

```
echo "<button type='submit' onclick='myModal('red','".$anytext']."');'>Click me</button>"
```

My modal:

```
<div id="changepopup">Error!</div>
```

Script:

```
 function myModal(color,text) {
  var x = document.getElementById("changepopup");

    // Zet text in modal
    x.innerHTML = text;

    // Zet kleur van modal
    x.style.background = color;

    // Add the "show" class to DIV
    x.className = "show";

    // After 3 seconds, remove the show class from DIV
    setTimeout(function(){ x.className = x.className.replace("show", ""); }, 3000);
  }
```

The button (As shown on the page):

```
<button type="submit" onclick="myModal(" red','jouw="" status="" is="" vernieuwd');'="">Click me</button>
```

What i try to archieve is that the notification popup comes up with the set color and text in it, while being inside an php echo.

Thank you guys and girls for helping me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oke i don't know why this works and the other way around not but my solution is:

```
echo "<button type='submit' onclick='"; echo 'myModal("red","'.$anytext'].'");'; echo"'>Click me</button>"
```

Comment: `onclick='myModal('red'` The client is interpreting only `myModal(` as the onclick-string since you are closing the string with the quotation marks of "red".